# How to call two constructors from two derived classes from the base class in a for-loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, inheritance, constructor

From my base class, I 'm trying to call two class constructors from two derived classes **each**.

I have two derived classes; I'll call them ClassA and ClassB. Both ClassA and ClassB have two derived classes of their own. I'll call them ClassA1, ClassA2, ClassB1, and ClassB2. These 4 classes have a constructor, but they both have different lengths.

The idea is to use an array and a for-loop to call each constructor. This is what I have so far:

```
public class Base {

    int year;
    String brand;
    String name;
    
    Base(){
        year = 0;
        brand = "Default";
        name = "Default";
    }
    
    Base(int year, String brand, String name){
        this.year = year;
        this.brand = brand;
        this.name = name;
    }
    void display(){
        System.out.println("Year: " + year + "\nBrand: " + brand
        + "\nName: " + name);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          
        Base obj[] = new Base[4];
        obj[0] = new Base(); //I'm not sure what to do here
        obj[1] = new Base();
        obj[2] = new Base();
        obj[3] = new Base();
        
        for (int i=0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            obj[i] = new Base();
        }
    }
}

public class ClassA extends Base {
    int playerCount;
    boolean hasMods;
    double fileSize;

    
    ClassA(){
        playerCount = 0;
        hasMods = false;
        fileSize = 0;
    }
    
    ClassA(int year, String brand, String name, int playerCount,
            boolean hasMods, double fileSize){
        super(year, brand, name);
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
        this.hasMods = hasMods;
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
    }
    
    void display(){
        super.display();
        System.out.println("Max Number of Players: " + playerCount
        + "\nModding Capability?: " + hasMods
        + "\nStorage: " + fileSize + " gb");
    }
}

class ClassA1 extends ClassA{
    ClassA1(){
        super(2015, "Bethesda", "Fallout 4", 1, true, 30.0);
    }
}

class ClassA2 extends ClassA{
    ClassA2(){
        super(2007, "Bungie", "Halo 3", 4, false, 6.3);
    }
}
```

Even with that array, it doesn't make much sense to me. If the array is from Base, I don't think it would call anything lower than it. If the array is ClassA, it still wouldn't get the specific classes. If it's ClassA1, then all the other classes cannot be called. And the array cannot be a string either obviously.

I'd imagine it to work like this: Array[x] value = new Arrayx;. The thing is, I'm not sure if that would even work, or how to do that.

If I can just see how it would work with one of the two classes, I believe I can figure it out with the other.

Comment: are you asking for something like `obj[0] = new ClassA1(); obj[1] = new ClassA2(); ...` ?

Comment: So you want an array with 1 instance of each class calling the *no-args constructor*?

Comment: A derived class can take the place of the parent class, so as @user85421 suggests, you simply create an instance of the child class and place it into the array. It'll call all of the parent constructors because of the `super()` calls. Leave the type of the array as `Base`. This is a fundamental concept in Object Oriented Programming known as **Polymorphism**.

Comment: @user85421 and Idle_Mind thank you both so much :'| 

Yes. that's exactly what I was trying to do.  I tried doing something very similar but it didn't work so I gave up on that entirely.

Comment: @TakeshiDBXV, can you provide more information about the data and its usage?  Try a database, _[SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html)_ is easy to use.

Comment: based on posted code, maybe your data model can be improved. For example, `ClassA1` and `ClassA2` seems to be just data holder, there is no different functionality. In that case, the next step would be doing `obj[0] = new ClassA(2015, "Bethesda", "Fallout 4", 1, true, 30.0);`  (and not have a `ClassA1`). Further, if these are *constant*, the use of `enum` can be recommended. The use of a database,  as suggested in previous comment, should also be considered (depending on usage, details)

Comment: What you are trying to achieve with this code is not easy to understand, but after reading the comments here, you basically need to create an array of objects of type `Base`. All of those objects just need to be of type `Base` but that is not an exclusive statement. All of your classes extend from `Base` and so instances of them can be part of the array. You just need to downcast if you need features of the sub-classes i.e. `obj[0] = new ClassA2()` -> `((ClassA2)obj[0]).whatever`.